# Some questions about linear rail systems

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, cnc

there are many linear rail system configurations. Some with only one lead/ball screw in the middle and a moving platform with wheels aligning outside/inside/on top of one/two framing rail(s). Others have two additional rods on each side passing through a linear bearings housing. What are the pros and cons of each configurations? If the load on the moving platform is heavy, in general which configuration is better?

Let's take two products as an example:

https://openbuildspartstore.com/c-beam-linear-actuator-bundle/

https://openbuildspartstore.com/c-beam-xlarge-linear-actuator-bundle/

In this case, is the standard version better because the wheels under the moving platform are closer to the center? Any advantage in having a larger moving platform in terms of moving a heavy load stably?

My concern is that they are using something called Xtreme Solid V Wheel sliding on the frame, rather than a pair of rods on linear bearing housings, to keep the platform on track. Another concern is that under the moving platform, they use Derlin as some kind of anti-backlash nut for that 8" lead screw. Are these two systems less stable/durable than those with two additional rods on the side and a metal nut to interact with the lead screw?

Comment: Screw is usually used to deliver force to move.  You will have that and forces from weight of items moved, and a "force" that opposes the acceleration of masses.  For best structure, flow any of these that you do not need into (nearby) supports that can handle them with minimal deflection.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I don't quite understand the last sentence for the best structure. Could you please clarify? Is it more stable if I have two side rods passing through linear bear housings than just rely on wheels sliding on the frames?

Comment: It is most stable if your supports are close to where they need to bear load.  This is usually close to where the loads originate, since transferring them elsewhere means more mass which in turn cause even more loads.  Rods vs wheels does not matter- great bearings can be used in either for great results.

Comment: Re: updated question ... they're all factors. It depends how good a bearing you really need, loads, tradeoff vs cost, etc. The stuff you linked with extrusions, compared to rods and bushings (or bearings), has the benefit of usually favorable cost, good stiffness, and convenience to mount it to other stuff. on the other hand, rods and conventional bearings offer lower friction and can be ground to very tight tolerances, if you're making a high precision machine (but there are a bunch of details to attend to as a designer to make it work nicely)

Comment: Is there a name for the two types of systems (two rods with bearings vs wheels on moving platform)?

Comment: Speaking of precision, I need to be able to measure the travel distance when the platform is moving at 0.01mm accuracy and resolution. Am I correct that those wheeled systems by Openbuilds are not be suitable as they will cause additional degrees of freedom? In this case, is it better to make or use a system with linear rail guides?

Comment: @lovedrinking - new question. Yes, if you want *repeatability* to 10um, any "play" in the rotation of the stage is probably unacceptable. A "biasing" side load to push the stage up against one side might do the trick, depending on loads from the application. Look at how it's done on machine tools or CMM equipment.

Comment: Thank you all..